# How to work around Firefox canvas text rendering bug?

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas

I have written a small JavaScript [library](https://github.com/ashmind/textmetrics) to calculate text height-related metrics.
It scans canvas image data to find top and bottom points of the text.

Unfortunately due to Firefox [Bug 737852](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=737852) it is currently broken in Firefox -- `top` position is higher than it should be, which breaks `fitHeight` logic.

Any suggestions on how I can work around that?

Comment: since you're scanning by hand, the actual position of the text shouldn't matter ??

Comment: @GameAlchemist Why? Let's say the text is "I". The position of the top pixel will depend on the position of the letter itself when it gets drawn on the canvas. If Firefox puts text 10 pixels higher than other browsers, y-coordinate of top pixel will be less by 10.

Then when it is put in a span (for example), all browsers will put it the same way (since it is only a canvas bug in Firefox). Therefore you can't fit it in the span properly.

Comment: Since you are drawing to measure, draw with some upper margin (32 on top and 32 below), then do a line by line scan, so you can detect height. Your library should handle -as long as this bug lives- a verticalOffset And/Or inject CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillText and drawText to correct the bug.

Comment: @GameAlchemist: I can't say I understand your proposed solution. Can you create it as an answer so here is more space for discussion? My main problem is that if offset can be dynamically incorrect depending on the font used. Even if I detect FF version, I am not sure how to find out the correct offset. Also I am not sure what margin of 32 achieves -- I can't draw text with background so I can't detect height of containing box from canvas.